# Show/hide sitemap if user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

I have a log in page, code behind is below:

```
protected void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbUsers;Integrated Security=True");
    conn1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where UserName = @user AND Password = @pass", conn1);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

    param.ParameterName = "@user";
    param1.ParameterName = "@pass";

    param.Value = txtuser.Text;
    param1.Value = txtpass.Text;

    cmdd.Parameters.Add(param);
    cmdd.Parameters.Add(param1);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();
        MessageBox("Login Successful");
        clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox("Invalid Username/Password");
    }

}
```

I have two sitemaps:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
                onmenuitemdatabound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">        
            </asp:Menu>      
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />

            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">              
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
                onmenuitemdatabound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">        
            </asp:Menu>      
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource2" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="AdminSiteMapProvider"/>
```

What I want to achieve is when a user is not logged in Menu1 will display and NavigationMenu will hide but if a user is logged in Menu1 will hide then NavigationMenu will show.

I'm using asp.net with C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
        reader.Read();
        // set as user authenticated 
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtuser.Text, true);
        MessageBox("Login Successful");
        clear();
}
```

In your PageLoad

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Menu1.Visible = false;
        NavigationMenu.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Menu1.Visible = true;
        NavigationMenu.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

OR

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    Menu1.Visible = !isAuthenticated;
    NavigationMenu.Visible =isAuthenticated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, have tried the code but it gives me an error saying "formsauthentication does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are probably better off using ASP.NET membership for this. From your example it looks like you are storing your passwords in plain text, which is bad. Take a read of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for how to set up asp.net membership.

Then, in order to achieve different a different view based on if the user is authenticated or not you can use the asp.net LoginView control like so:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView0" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
            EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
            onmenuitemdatabound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">        
        </asp:Menu>      
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource2" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="AdminSiteMapProvider"/>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
            EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
            onmenuitemdatabound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">        
        </asp:Menu>      
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I hope this helps.